# f.label not working with block in haml

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have following haml code

```
form_for @user_notification_settings_form do |f|
  = f.label :follow do
    div dummy
```

But it generates

```
<label for="user_notification_settings_form_follow">
  foruser_notification_settings_form_follow
</label>
```

Where as I was expecting it to generate

```
<label for="user_notification_settings_form_follow">
  <div>dummy</div>
</label>
```

Deubugging into rails I found :

`label_tag` within `form_tag_helper` has `&block` but when it calls `content_tag` in `tag_helper` , `&block` now becomes nil

```
  def label_tag(name = nil, content_or_options = nil, options = nil, &block)
    options = content_or_options if block_given? && content_or_options.is_a?(Hash)
    options ||= {}
    options.stringify_keys!
    options["for"] = sanitize_to_id(name) unless name.blank? || options.has_key?("for")
    content_tag :label, content_or_options || name.to_s.humanize, options, &block
  end
  def content_tag(name, content_or_options_with_block = nil, options = nil, escape = true, &block)
    if block_given?
      options = content_or_options_with_block if content_or_options_with_block.is_a?(Hash)
      content_tag_string(name, capture(&block), options, escape)
    else
      content_tag_string(name, content_or_options_with_block, options, escape)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the `%div` element and then nest the text for the label in it.

```
form_for @user_notification_settings_form do |f|
  = f.label :follow do
    %div 
      dummy
```

Comment: any reason for `%div` ?